# Failed to connect php server to apple apns

Tags: iphone, apns-php

I am developing an app in which apple push notification service is using. I downloaded an ssl certificate and bind it with private key (in keychain) and convert it in .pem format for php server . But when am going to connect to apns through php by providing .pem certificate and pass-phrase and device token it gives me an error Failed to connect. I tried sending push notification using PushMeBaby application in that case am able to receive notification. But why failed to connect from php server .... Please help me to resolve this problem..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of things that you can try to debug the connection failure.

1. Make sure when you export the certificate from the keychain that you are not including the private key as part of the export. ONLY export the certificate.
2. Are you trying to connect to the correct server? In case of sandbox environment you must be connecting to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com (coupled with the development certificate) and connecting to gateway.push.apple.com (coupled with production certificate) when using the production environment.
3. Lastly take a look at this portion from the Apple's APNs documentation ([The Binary Interface and Notification Formats](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html))"If you send a notification and APNs finds the notification malformed or otherwise unintelligible, it returns an error-response packet prior to disconnecting. (If there is no error, APNs doesn’t return anything.)" This should give you an idea of what's going wrong.